# Plotting points in SpatialPointsDataFrame format by attributes R

Tags: r, plot, attributes, points

I would like to plot the SpatialPointsDataFrame points over raster by attributes `attr1`. Specifically, I would like 1's to be red and 0's to be blue circles. Help will be appreciated.

```
s <- 1          # scale
increment <- seq(-6,6,1)             # Create a sequence of x values
y=matrix(0,length(increment))

for (i in 1:length(increment)) {
        y[i] <- 1/(1+ exp(-(increment[i])/s))
}


# Create matrix:
rep <- 8

valuematrix <- replicate(rep,y[,1])


library(sp)
library(raster)

raster <- raster(valuematrix)

# Create SpatialPointsDataFrame

x <- c(0.2,0.04,0.7)
y <- c(0.34,0.5,0.9)
attr1 <- c(0,1,0)
attr2 <- c(32,13,30)

data_DF <- data.frame(x,y,attr1,attr2)
colnames(data_DF) <- c("x","y","attr1","attr2")

coords <- data.frame(data_DF$x, data_DF$y)
coords <- SpatialPoints(coords, proj4string=CRS(as.character(NA)), bbox = NULL)
initialdata_DF <- data.frame(coords,data_DF$attr1,data_DF$attr2)
initialdata_SPDF <- SpatialPointsDataFrame(coords,initialdata_DF)

plot(raster)
plot(initialdata_SPDF, add=TRUE)
```

Comment: `plot(raster) ; points(coordinates(initialdata_SPDF), col=c("blue", "red"))`

Comment: thanks, but this is only alternating blue and red colors for points. if I put 0 and 1's in different (not alternating) order, this command doesn't do the job

Comment: try: `plot(raster) ; points(coordinates(initialdata_SPDF), col=c(`0`="blue", `1`="red")[as.character(initialdata_SPDF$data_DF.attr1)])`